# How to detect a hologram from an image?

Tags: android, image-processing

Using the camera i  am taking an image which contains a hologram and i want to detect it and save that hologram as an image . is it possible in java .

Comment: ok , is it possible to detect a watermark with android device camera ?

Comment: this question is too unspecific and vague.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that camera can capture this information in image, you can perform  whatever image processing algorythms you like with java.